# Credit/Debit formatting when inserting into a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Say I have a temp table like so:

```
create table #temptable
    (
        RecordId int,
        Balance money NOT NULL,
    )
```

I'm now populating this temporary table with data taken from a stored procedure that is passed only a customer reference.

```
Insert into #temptable 
exec getstatementhistory @cust_ref
```

I now want to do some updates/inserts into a different table, using the information that has been stored in `#temptable`. I have a problem though, I want all debits to be stored in `#temptable` like so `103.85` and all credits to be stored in `#temptable` like this `-103.85`

The problem I have, is the stored procedure reverses this convention so debits are formatted like this     `-103.85` and credits like this `103.85`

What I require is to specify in the `INSERT INTO #temptable` to reverse the balance convention.

**i.e** if it is passed  `-103.85` from the SP, store it in `#temptable` as `103.85` and vice versa.

Can anyone suggest a way of changing my insert statement to control the credit/debit format for the `Balance` field in my temporary table.

Comment: Can you paste your current `INSERT` statement? Basically you would have to negate the value inserted into `balance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert into #temptable 
exec getstatementhistory @cust_ref

--After the Insert, update the contents to reverse the format

Update #temptable
set Balance = Balance*-1
```